# search with enter key

Tags: jquery, search, enter

I have a real estate plugin that I use for my website. The search tool of this plugin does not work with the enter key on the keyboard. I want to search with the enter key after typing a keyword in the search tool. how can I do that?

my site: https://memoshome.com

I think the relevant code is this :

```
$('.ere-advanced-search-btn', css_class_wrap).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var search_form = $(this).closest('.search-properties-form'),
                search_url = search_form.data('href'),
                search_field = [],
                query_string = '?';
            if (search_url.indexOf('?') !== -1) {
                query_string = '&';
            }
            $('.search-field', search_form).each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    field_name = $this.attr('name'),
                    current_value = $this.val(),
                    default_value = $this.data('default-value');
                if (current_value != default_value) {
                    search_field[field_name] = current_value;
                }
            });
            $('.ere-sliderbar-filter', search_form).each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    field_name_min = $this.find('.min-input-request').attr('name'),
                    field_name_max = $this.find('.max-input-request').attr('name'),
                    current_value_min = $this.find('.min-input-request').val(),
                    current_value_max = $this.find('.max-input-request').val(),
                    default_value_min = $this.data('min-default'),
                    default_value_max = $this.data('max-default');
                if (current_value_min != default_value_min || current_value_max != default_value_max) {
                    search_field[field_name_min] = current_value_min;
                    search_field[field_name_max] = current_value_max;
                }
            });
            var other_features = '';
            $('[name="other_features"]', search_form).each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    value = $this.attr('value');
                if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                    other_features += value + ";";
                }
            });
            if (other_features !== '') {
                other_features = other_features.substring('0', other_features.length - 1);
                search_field['other_features'] = other_features;
            }
            if (search_field !== []) {
                for (var k in search_field) {
                    if (search_field.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                        query_string += k + "=" + search_field[k] + "&";
                    }
                }
            }
            query_string = query_string.substring('0', query_string.length - 1);
            window.location.href = search_url + query_string;
        });
```

Comment: i have not problem with enter key (on chrome)

Comment: also search tool is not in <form> tag

Comment: it will be difficult to help you more if we dont have a sample  showing the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing `'click'`  with `'submit'` may work if you add this to your btn `type="submit"`

Comment: i've tried this before. search tool is not in <form> tag. can it be so.

Answer (score 0):

In your search input text box, try this:

```
$('.my-search-box').keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
    $('.ere-advanced-search-btn', css_class_wrap).click();
    return;  
  }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

without html code, you could try:

```
$('.my-search-box').keydown((ev) => {//i suppose .my-search-box' is class of input search
  if (ev.which == 13 ){//enter   
     $('give the id/class of button search').trigger("click");
  }
});
```

you trap if event is enter in input search box, so you trigger a click on button search

Comment: @devo-zara glad to help you dont forget  to validate and upvote the answer. That will close the question and that is like that stakoverflow runs

Comment: I noticed another problem. When I change the input value, it cannot detect.
example: https://memoshome.com/en/advanced-search/?status=for-sale&keyword=itemtitle

If I change the place where it says itemtitle and press enter, the value does not change. but if I press the search button with the mouse then it changes.

Comment: @devo-zara its difficult to test on a real web site, you have to reproduce the same problem on a snippet.functional.. so i dont see the problem.....